# How to accept insecure connection in Firefox 39+?

Tags: linux, firefox, security

When I try to open a webpage, I get an `ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key` error in Firefox.

According to my googling [the keys are weak, there is a security hole, I'm not safe, etc.](https://support.mozilla.org/hu/questions/1065417) Great, Firefox protects me. My only problem is that this is an intranet connection, so I'm pretty sure that nobody will try to hack me, IT just didn't update that server in a long time.

If I remember right in previous versions (I don't exactly know which versions, but then the error message included a yellow sign with a police officer too. Now I'm on 39.0) Firefox had an option to accept such connections. Is there a hidden way to still accept insecure connections like this? Maybe something in `about:config` that I can temporarily change manually?

Comment: The better fix is to ask IT to update it! +1

Comment: Sure. Let's assume that I need to access that page a little faster than IT solves problems. :)

Comment: Does a different browser not work then to get the data faster? In IE, can you add it to a safe zone or does the issue still persist

Comment: I don't have IE, I'm on Linux. But I'll try Chrome to see if it helps.

Comment: Chrome still seems to have an option to manually approve going to unsecure sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from another source, but I'll also post it here for future reference:

Apparently Firefox's `about:config` does have settings for disabling security protocols. In my case disabling `security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha` and `security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha` forces Firefox to use a stronger cypher and I can access the same page from Firefox too, without waiting for IT to fix it.

I don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to ask IT to fix it, but as you said in your comments, you're more desperate for a quicker fix.

Also as per the comments, try a different browser.

Since Chrome works for you, use that!

Comment: > "The best answer is to ask IT to fix it" - sorry to disillusion anyone about the reality of large corporations with huge intranets, but majority of small helper-servers of non-production value there will just never going to get updated. No chances. While depending project must be completed no matter what and no one is interested to hear about busy inefficient IT and smart caring FF. That's the life - take it or quit that job. :-) Glad to see the solution below about the workaround that just works sans any drama

Answer (score 0):

Being in the same situation as you, I use [SkipCert Error](https://github.com/foudfou/skipCertError).

But it doesn't fix `sec_error_bad_der`, [bug#1148766](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1148766).